# Combine empty list with other items in RxJava

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I'm trying to combine multiple observables into one with the following code:

```
 val observables: Array<Observable<out MyItem>> = arrayOf(
    obs0,
    obs1
    obs2,
    obs3,
    obs4.flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it) },
    obs5,
    obs6,
    obs7,
    obs8,
    obs9,
    obs10
)

Observable.combineLatestDelayError(observables) { items ->
    items.filterIsInstance<MyItem>()
        .filter { ... }
        .map { ... }
}
```

All of them has a type of `Observable<MyItem>`, except `obs4` is `Observable<List<MyItem>>`, so I want to unpack it in the result list with `.flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it) }`. The problem here is if `obs4` emits an empty list then the resulting chain never emits, because `combineLatest` waits for all sources to emit first item.
Is there any operator that would emit on every change of every source ignoring empty sources?

Comment: How many items do you expect from each `obs0`...`obs10`? Does it matter which `MyItem` came from which `obs`? Perhaps you can use `merge`, `toList` and `map` instead of `combineLatest`.

Comment: There can be from 1 up to 4 items in each `obs`, but I don't know the exact number, and yes order matters. I guess `merge`+`toList` is not an option, since I need multiple emissions not a `Single`. I might end up using `Any` as an Array type parameter and unsafe casting in combiner to create a list.

Comment: You could introduce a placeholder `MyItem` and use `defaultIfEmpty` with `fromIterable` so you do have a value from obs4.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Fortunately, I can add stub `MyItem` implementation